# Problema actividad java

Tags: java, diccionarios, hashmap

Tengo que pasar a java este ejercicio de diccionarios que he hecho en python, pero no se como continuar ya que en java no puedo usar el break porque mi profesor lo considera trampa.
Python:

```
precios = {"manzana": 2, "naranja": 1.5, "platano": 4, "piña": 3}
while True:
fruta = input("Dime la fruta que has vendido:")
if fruta.lower() not in precios:
    print("Fruta no existe.")
else:
    cantidad = int(input("Dime la cantidad de frutas que has vendido:"))
    print("El precio es de %f" % (cantidad * precios[fruta]))
opcion = input("¿Quieres vender otra fruta (s/n)")
while opcion.lower() != "s" and opcion.lower() != "n":
    opcion = input("¿Quieres vender otra fruta (s/n)")
if opcion.lower() == "n":
    break
```

Y esto es lo que tengo hecho de Java:

```
System.out.println("Ejercicio 3");
    HashMap<String, Integer> e3 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    e3.put("naranja", 2);
    e3.put("manzana", 1);
    e3.put("melón", 5);
    Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int j = 0;
    while(j <= 0);
        String fruta = sc3.nextLine();
        if (fruta:e3){
    
}
```

Comment: No es que me de un error, sino que tenemos prohibido usarlo en java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo espero te sirva.

```
    HashMap<String, Double> precios = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fruta;
    
    precios.put("manzana", 2.0);
    precios.put("naranja", 1.5);
    precios.put("platano", 4.0);
    precios.put("pina", 3.0);
    
    // EL TRUCO ES USAR UNA BANDERA EN LUGAR DEL BREAK PARA CONTROLAR EL WHILE
    char respuesta = 0;
    do{                                                 // while True:
        System.out.println("Dime la fruta que has vendido:");           // fruta = input("Dime la fruta que has vendido:")
        fruta = input.next();                                       // fruta = input("Dime la fruta que has vendido:")
        if(precios.get(fruta) == null) {                                        // if fruta.lower() not in precios:
            System.out.println("Fruta no existe");                                  // print("Fruta no existe.")
        }else{
            System.out.println("Dime la cantidad de frutas que has vendido:");
            double cantidad = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("El precio es de "+ (cantidad * precios.get(fruta)));
        }
        System.out.println("Quieres vender otra fruta (s/n)");
        respuesta = input.next().charAt(0);
    }while( respuesta != 'n' );
```

Comment: Si muchas gracias